# Tabularx inside a box

Tags: tables, pdftex, tabularx, tcolorbox

How can I do to put a tabularx object inside a box?
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,title=Title] Text

\tcblower

\begin{table}
\caption{\textbf{Title of the table.}}
\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{bb}
\hline
\textbf{Model} & \textbf{Description}\\
\hline
A & B\\
C & E\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{table2}
\end{table}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

> LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

Because it's not possible to write a table inside a box. Even when I remove the table environment and only keep the tabularx environment I get the same error. Isn't it possible to write a table inside a box?

Comment: unrelated to the question but `{bb}` can not work as `tabular` column specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table environment always wants to be the outermost defined but will appear inside the box nevertheless:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[english]{babel} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{amsfonts} \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{tcolorbox} \usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document} 


\begin{table}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,title=Title] Text

\tcblower

\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll}
\hline
\textbf{Model} & \textbf{Description}\\
\hline
A & B\\
C & E\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{\textbf{Title of the table.}}
\label{table2}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: Also note that `tabularx` usually only takes `{l}` and/or `{X}` without more complex definitions of alignment/width.

Comment: On the other hand, `ll` makes little sense in `tabularx`: at least one column should be declared as `X` (probably the second one, in this case).

Comment: @egreg yes, I forgot to mention that the {bb} that was there in the original tablularx code doesn't work. But since it was not the main issue of the question I decided not to make an issue of it. Personally I have tabularx environments in my thesis with only {l} but I use tabularx in all table environments for consistency. That might be a matter of taste. I have edited my answer to include the tablularx information.

Answer (score 1):

A `table` is a floating environment which usually contains a `tabular`. What I suppose you want is just a `tabular` with a `caption` which can be easily written forgetting the external `table` environment. In this case the `caption` can be written with the `\captionof` command from `capt-of` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,title=Title] Text

\tcblower
\captionof{table}{\textbf{Title of the table.}}\label{table2}
\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\hline
\textbf{Model} & \textbf{Description}\\
\hline
A & B\\
C & E\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]